# Wordpress Does not grab the string sends useing AJAX response, wp_ajax hook

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

The problem with my code is that it seems to be working. The AJAX request is success, but it doesn't return any data with the current setup I have (e.g is return me `Notice: Undefined index: time in ...` even I send the ajax requere with, `$time` is `$_POST['time']`)
Here is the js script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $('#date').datepicker({
              onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                  $(this).attr("disabled", false);         
                  showIntervalAvailabel();//show the interval available
              },
               
    });
   function showIntervalAvailabel() {
                var datePickedByUser = $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd,MM,yyyy' }).val(); //to get the date selected by the user
                  console.log ("start ajax  to send");
                  $.ajax({
                    url:xDates.ajaxurl, 
                    type:'POST',
                    // get the selected values from 3 form fields
                    //data:'interval_selected_by_user=' + datePickedByUser,
                    data: { 
                      action : 'test_booking',
                      time: datePickedByUser,
                    },
                    success :function(response) {
                      console.log('is sending the date '+ datePickedByUser);
                    },
                    error :function(response){
                        alert("failure");
                    } 
               
                  });
```

the pluginname.php - plugin function page

firsly I called the ajaxurl

```
add_action('init', 'register_script_for_plugin');
function register_script_for_plugin() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', plugins_url('/includes/js_scripts_plugin.js', __FILE__), array(), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
        wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'xDates', array( 
            'theWebsiteUrl' => get_site_url(),
            'thePluginUrl' => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ),
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
            ) );
}
```

secondly I called the function  `wp-ajax-ACTION`

```
 //create callback to show using JSON
 add_action('wp_ajax_test_booking','test_test'); 
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_booking','test_test'); 
 function test_test() {
    //$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);
    error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
    var_dump($_POST);
    //require_once($path."wp-load.php");
    echo 'hello<br>';
    if(isset($_POST['time'])) {
        $time = $_POST['time'];
    echo $time;
    die();
    } else {
        echo 'does not work, is not isset';
    }
    
 }
add_shortcode( 'show_code_tests', 'test_test' );
```

Here is returning me `does not work, is not isset` even if I send the string using AJAX

**EDIT -  how I fixed the issue, the problem was I had to loop the php response inside the JAVASCRIPT, no in the php function**
I find myself the solution. The problem was in my js script where I added inside the `success :function(response)` the  `$('#results_show_test').html(data);` and I create a  where I wanted to show the results. And Also I deleted the `add_shortcode( 'show_code_tests', 'test_test' );`

Comment: That's more likely that you are not getting any value in your JS variable "datePickedByUser".

You can console.log(datePickedByUser) and see if you get any value?

Comment: It is working, is showing me the value in console.log, anything else, i am really stuck in this issue

Comment: I tested your code on my machine it is working fine. The only time it failed when the variable "datePickedByUser" is type of "undefined".

Comment: does not matter, You can try a any value and in the `console.log('test');` is working, maybe the problem is on my plugin, is any method to check if the `wp-ajax` works in a plugin? maybe there is a problem ....

Comment: I find myself the solution. The problem was in my `js script` where I added in  `success :function(response) ` the ` $('#results_show_test').html(data);`  and I create a `<div id="results_show_test"></div>` where I wanted to show the results. And Also I deleted the `add_shortcode( 'show_code_tests', 'test_test' );` from the php page